# Are upgrades within the same major version guaranteed to be compatible for the device?

Tags: android

Is it reasonable to assume that all devices running Android 4.1 could be upgraded to Android 4.4? Or do system requirements change with minor upgrades?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it reasonable to assume that all devices running Android 4.1 could be upgraded to Android 4.4?

IMHO, no, simply because "all" is a rather expansive term.

Within the confines of the Google Play ecosystem, there are some changes in the [Compatibility Definition Document (CDD) requirements](https://source.android.com/compatibility/cdd) between 4.1 and 4.4 (e.g., minimum available storage raised to 1GB). You would need to create a detailed diff of requirements, then decide which subset of those requirements you care about, then determine which devices meet the requirements for 4.1 and 4.4.

And for devices outside of the Google Play ecosystem, anything goes. Most likely, some non-Play devices shipped with 4.1 that did not meet the CDD requirements for 4.1, as non-Play devices are not obligated to comply with the CDD. Such devices are even less likely to be able to run 4.4 successfully.